# Where should my automatic screen change occur - presentation or model?

Tags: flutter

I am using scopedModel approach in flutter, but the question still remains with other patterns like flutter.

-My UI calls authModel.login()

-authModel.login does async work and calls notifyListeners

-build is automatically triggered on my UI

-inside build method, UI checks the login state on authModel, then calls
addPostFrameCallback to change the screen from the build method.

Is this the best design? I feel like this is code smell, but I am not sure. Would it be better if the authModel was passed an onLoginCompleteCallback function from the UI that would change the screen, and then I would not need to call addPostFrameCallback in the build method?

The presentation on the screen is not dependant on the isLoggedIn bool at all. Its just observed to change the screen.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you added some code.

Comment: I disagree. I think it is a pure design question.